# User Defined Target in Rajwali-Vuforia

Tags: android, vuforia, rajawali

Please help me. I use Rajawali 3D framework integrating with vuforia. How if i want use user defined target vuforia with Rajawali? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method
    createImageMarker("target.xml");
Put your files (.xml + .dat export on https://developer.vuforia.com/targetmanager/deviceTarget/deviceTargetListing) in "assets" repertory.